# How do you use jpeg_streamer

Tags: ros, mjpeg-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, but I ran [jpeg_streamer](http://ros.org/wiki/jpeg_streamer) and another node that publishes a compressed image but now what do I do? Tried to connect a web browser to localhost:8080 but nothing happened. Expected to see my camera image sent as an jpeg stream.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30461/how-do-you-use-jpeg_streamer/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I figured it out ... run:

```
rosrun jpeg_streamer jpeg_streamer image:=image_raw/compressed
```

Then go to localhost:8080 in your web browser.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-03-17**:
That's not valid syntax... Params should be prefixed by an underscore. That said, neither syntax works for me. It just hangs indefinitely and outputs no status.